# Oracle round varchar2 column to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rounding

I have a varchar2 column that i need to get an average number from.

So take the following table where val is a column varchar2(20):

```
 val
 5
 4.654645
 3.4534353
```

I have tried the following:

```
select ROUND(AVG(TO_NUMBER(val)),2) as n from table
```

The result i am getting is 1.9110E+13

The result i want is a number rounded to 2 decimal places

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a varchar2 field?

Comment: I did not create this table so not sure but i can't change column type

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps . . .

```
select CAST(AVG(TO_NUMBER(val)) as decimal(20, 2)) as n
from table;
```

Why are you storing numbers as strings?  That seems like abad design decision.

Comment: I agree but this is not something i can change.

Comment: So i get same result

Comment: @Maxqueue . . . Then the format of the result is probably a function of the app where you are running the query.

Answer (score 0):

So the following worked for me:

```
select ROUND(AVG(CAST((val) as decimal(20, 2))),2) as n from table
```

Thanks for suggestions